# Accessing user-mode memory inside kernel-mode driver

Tags: c++, windows, kernel

What I wanna reach is:

1. UM-App sends DeviceIoControl to my driver telling the PID and virtual address to operate.
2. KM-Driver reads from or writes to the specified memory of the specified process.
3. KM-Driver sends back the result (if any).
4. UM-App reads the result.

Seems easy, yeah, but whatever I tried - failed (crashed), that's why I'm posting here.

1. Tried to attach to the process and access the memory directly.
2. Tried to attach to the process and access the memory via MDLs.

Here is the full code of my routine:

```
NTSTATUS DriverCallback_IoControl_Internal_VMOperation(IRP* _IRP, IO_STACK_LOCATION* _IRPStack, ULONG* _ResultLength)
{
    NTSTATUS result = STATUS_SUCCESS;

    KIRQL kirql = KeGetCurrentIrql();

    switch (kirql)
    {
        case PASSIVE_LEVEL:
        {
            DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "[%s] %s: IRQL = [%s]", "km_helper", "DriverCallback_IoControl_Internal_VMOperation", "PASSIVE_LEVEL");

            break;
        }

        case APC_LEVEL:
        {
            DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "[%s] %s: IRQL = [%s]", "km_helper", "DriverCallback_IoControl_Internal_VMOperation", "APC_LEVEL");

            break;
        }

        case DISPATCH_LEVEL:
        {
            DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "[%s] %s: IRQL = [%s]", "km_helper", "DriverCallback_IoControl_Internal_VMOperation", "DISPATCH_LEVEL");

            break;
        }

        default:
        {
            DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "[%s] %s: IRQL = [%d]", "km_helper", "DriverCallback_IoControl_Internal_VMOperation", kirql);

            break;
        }
    }

    if (kirql > DISPATCH_LEVEL) // some APIs we use can't run if IRQL is too high.
    {
        DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "[%s] %s: BAD IRQL.", "km_helper", "DriverCallback_IoControl_Internal_VMOperation");

        return STATUS_INVALID_LEVEL;
    }

    if (_IRP->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer)
    {
        if (_ResultLength)
        {
            *_ResultLength = 0;

            if (_IRPStack->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.OutputBufferLength >= _IRPStack->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.InputBufferLength)
            {
                CMemoryPacket* mem = reinterpret_cast<CMemoryPacket*>(_IRP->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer);

                DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "[%s] %s: PID: [%08X] Virtual Address: [%08X] Length: [%08X] Type: [%d]", "km_helper", "DriverCallback_IoControl_Internal_VMOperation", mem->ProcessId, mem->Address, mem->Size, mem->Type);

                PEPROCESS process = NULL;
                result = PsLookupProcessByProcessId(reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(mem->ProcessId), &process);

                if (NT_SUCCESS(result))
                {
                    PEPROCESS xd = PsGetCurrentProcess();
                    HANDLE id = PsGetCurrentProcessId();

                    DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "[%s] %s: EProcess: [%08X] ID: [%08X] Target: [%08X].", "km_helper", "DriverCallback_IoControl_Internal_VMOperation", xd, id, process);

                    KAPC_STATE apcState;
                    KeStackAttachProcess(process, &apcState);

                    xd = PsGetCurrentProcess();
                    id = PsGetCurrentProcessId();

                    DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "[%s] %s: EProcess: [%08X] ID: [%08X] Target: [%08X].", "km_helper", "DriverCallback_IoControl_Internal_VMOperation", xd, id, process);

                    void* Buffer_Source = NULL;
                    void* Buffer_Target = NULL;
                    MDL* Buffer_MDL = IoAllocateMdl(reinterpret_cast<void*>(mem->Address), mem->Size, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);

                    if (Buffer_MDL)
                    {
                        void* mdl_va = MmGetMdlVirtualAddress(Buffer_MDL);

                        DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "[%s] %s: MDL: [%08X] VA: [%08X]", "km_helper", "DriverCallback_IoControl_Internal_VMOperation", Buffer_MDL, mdl_va);

                        switch (mem->Type)
                        {
                            case MEMORYOPERATION::MO_READ:
                            {
                                // calling RtlCopyMemory directly has no difference at all, crashes too.

                                __try
                                {
                                    MmProbeAndLockPages(Buffer_MDL, MODE::UserMode, LOCK_OPERATION::IoReadAccess); // crashes here. tried both KernelMode and UserMode access.
                                }
                                __except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
                                {
                                    DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "[%s] %s: %s", "km_helper", "DriverCallback_IoControl_Internal_VMOperation", "MmProbeAndLockPages exploded...");

                                    IoFreeMdl(Buffer_MDL);

                                    KeUnstackDetachProcess(&apcState);
                                    ObDereferenceObject(process);

                                    return STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION;
                                }

                                // execution flow doesn't even hit here.

                                __try
                                {
                                    Buffer_Source = MmMapLockedPagesSpecifyCache(Buffer_MDL, MODE::UserMode, MEMORY_CACHING_TYPE::MmCached, NULL, FALSE, MM_PAGE_PRIORITY::NormalPagePriority);
                                }
                                __except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
                                {
                                    DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "[%s] %s: %s", "km_helper", "DriverCallback_IoControl_Internal_VMOperation", "MmMapLockedPagesSpecifyCache exploded...");

                                    MmUnlockPages(Buffer_MDL);
                                    IoFreeMdl(Buffer_MDL);

                                    KeUnstackDetachProcess(&apcState);
                                    ObDereferenceObject(process);

                                    return STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION;
                                }

                                if (Buffer_Source)
                                {
                                    Buffer_Target = mem->Data;

                                    __try
                                    {
                                        RtlCopyMemory(Buffer_Target, Buffer_Source, mem->Size);
                                    }
                                    __except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
                                    {
                                        DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "[%s] %s: %s", "km_helper", "DriverCallback_IoControl_Internal_VMOperation", "RtlCopyMemory exploded...");

                                        MmUnmapLockedPages(Buffer_Source, Buffer_MDL);
                                        MmUnlockPages(Buffer_MDL);
                                        IoFreeMdl(Buffer_MDL);

                                        KeUnstackDetachProcess(&apcState);
                                        ObDereferenceObject(process);

                                        return STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION;
                                    }

                                    mem->DataSize = mem->Size;
                                    *_ResultLength = mem->DataSize;

                                    MmUnmapLockedPages(Buffer_Source, Buffer_MDL);
                                }
                                else DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "[%s] %s: ERROR %d (%08X).", "km_helper", "DriverCallback_IoControl_Internal_VMOperation", 3, STATUS_NO_MEMORY);

                                MmUnlockPages(Buffer_MDL);

                                break;
                            }

                            case MEMORYOPERATION::MO_WRITE:
                            {
                                // TODO.

                                break;
                            }

                            case MEMORYOPERATION::MO_QUERY:
                            {
                                // TODO.

                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        IoFreeMdl(Buffer_MDL);
                    }
                    else DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "[%s] %s: ERROR %d (%08X).", "km_helper", "DriverCallback_IoControl_Internal_VMOperation", 2, STATUS_NO_MEMORY);

                    KeUnstackDetachProcess(&apcState);
                    ObDereferenceObject(process);
                }
                else DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "[%s] %s: ERROR %d (%08X).", "km_helper", "DriverCallback_IoControl_Internal_VMOperation", 1, result);
            }
            else result = STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW;
        }
        else result = STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;
    }
    else result = STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;

    return result;
}
```

The buffer provided to the driver can be everything (.text/.data section, heap, etc.). I know there are also some other ways to access non-paged pool (didn't test them though), but I want to make the universal way working.

The thing I also didn't try is reading/writing through the kernel API (ZwRead/WriteVirtualMemory), but this is not what I want to use.

By the way, I test my code in **VirtualBox VM** (Win7 SP1 x86), can it be the reason of crashing? Sadly I have no other environments to test on.

The result from DbgView is:
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDwh9.png)

Comment: Using reserved identifiers without need, in this case names like `_IRP` starting with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter, is just asking for trouble. That's the first I would change.

Comment: yeah, just noticed the collision too. but anyways, vs13 seems to be smart enough to handle that.

Comment: You wrote this in C++?  I didn't know that was possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so it wasn't a problem in the code, but in the environment. The code works fine now.

I was reading invalid memory address due to module base randomization. Didn't look at it carefully... Changed this parameter inside project->linker settings.

Comment: I was reading invalid memory address due to module base randomization. Didn't look at it carefully... Changed this parameter inside project->linker settings.

Comment: Did you change the parameter in the driver's build settings, or in the build settings for the application that was calling DeviceIoControl?  (I don't quite see how either would explain it - were you using a hard-coded address??!)

Comment: well, it's my mistake. i was trying to read dos header from my test program and a string inside it, assuming they are located on static addresses. i disabled module base randomization inside test program project and now i got what i want.

Comment: How did ASLR (randomization) cause this issue?  You first set context to that of the user-mode process and then you build the Mdl.  I don't see how randomization can break it, thanks.